# How to get the width and height of an image from a remote location in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I have created an 'Ext.Img' with Ext.create and assigned a remote url to the src attribute. Now i want to know the width and height of the image from the remote location.

i have gone through all the events for Ext.Img but didnt got which is the correct event to register. Did any body have any idea to find out the width and height of the image.

Thanks
Tapaswini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
        src: 'http://www.davey.com/elements/skin/home_tree.png',
        /*style: 'visibility: hidden;',*/
        listeners: {
            render: function() {
                this.mon(this.getEl(), 'load', function(e) {
                    console.log(this.getWidth());
                    console.log(this.getHeight());
                });
            }
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

Notice that image component must be rendered, and should also be displayed. Otherwise you will get 0x0 dimensions. You can use `visibility:hidden` to hide it.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/U769Y/ (see console)